# How to retrieve spring data repository instance for given domain class?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Given the list of all spring data repositories in some class `Bar`:

```
@Autowired
private List<Repository> repositories;
```

How can I find the repository for an existing domain class `Foo` in the above list?

Assuming that the following exists:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
  ...
}
```

and

```
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {}
```

Answer (score 29):

Spring Data Commons contains a class `Repositories` that takes a `ListableBeanFactory` to find all repository beans defined in it and exposes an API to obtain these instances by domain class (through `….getRepository(Class<?> type)`).

This class should be used with care. As there's some serious proxy generation going on for the repository instances you have to make sure the `Repositories` instance is created as late as possible during the `ApplicationContext` creation. The preferred way is to implement `ApplicationListener` and create the instance by listening to the `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

In case you're writing a  web application, the safest way to use `Repositories` is by bootstrapping the repositories in the `ApplicationContext` created by the `ContextLoaderListener` and place the `Repositories` (see the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) of Spring MVC for details.

Answer (score 21):

```
@Service
public class GenericRepository {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext appContext;

    Repositories repositories = null;

    public GenericRepository() {
        repositories = new Repositories(appContext);
    }

    public JpaRepository getRepository(AbstractPersistable entity) {
        return (JpaRepository) repositories.getRepositoryFor(entity.getClass());
    }

    public Object save(AbstractPersistable entity) {
        return getRepository(entity).save(entity);
    }

    public Object findAll(AbstractPersistable entity) {
        return getRepository(entity).findAll();
    }

    public void delete(AbstractPersistable entity) {
        getRepository(entity).delete(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The key to the solution is 
Spring's `org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.DefaultRepositoryMetadata` which provides the method `getDomainType()`.

`DefaultRepositoryMetadata` needs the repository interface as constructor arg. So one can loop over all existing repositories, retrieve the repository interface (which is still a tricky part because the repository instance has more than one interface) and find the one where `getDomainType()`equals `Foo.class`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
Repositories repositories = new Repositories(context);
CrudRepository repo = (CrudRepository) repositories.
            getRepositoryFor(entityClass).get();
```

Comment: Instance of check before casting>

Answer (score 2):

I will give my opinion based on my recent experience to make reflection in some classes or interfaces in Spring Boot.

As [@ekcrisp said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71701611/7164184) above:

> You can use Spring's GenericTypeResolver to get the Entity class from your Repository.

My experience: unfortunately the common ways of reflection don't work to get the `<T>` entity class in a  Spring Boot's repository. I tried in a lot of maneers. But this **`GenericTypeResolver`** actually could get the generics `<T>` type from `JpaRepository<T, ID>`.

In other words, the function below can provide all generic types of a class as an array. Then you can choose one of them:

```
public Class<?>[] getGenericType( Class<?> classInstance, Class<?> classToGetGenerics ) {
    return GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments( classInstance, classToGetGenerics );
}
```

This answer is about this stack and its versions:

JDK 11, Spring Boot 2.7.11 with Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA, and others libs. Posted in 2023-05-11.

---

If you want to add a solution in your "ObjectUtil" local solution, maybe these methods can be useful to get generic types, in any position, like get `<T>` or `<ID>` in `JpaRepository<T, ID>`:

```
@UtilityClass
public class ObjectUtil {
    // ...

    /**
     *
     * @param classInstance
     * @param classToGetGenerics
     *
     * @return the generic classes of the given param, based on class to get generics param.
     *
     * @see GenericTypeResolver#resolveTypeArguments
     */
    public static Class<?>[] getGenericType( Class<?> classInstance, Class<?> classToGetGenerics ) {
        return GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArguments( classInstance, classToGetGenerics );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param classInstance
     * @param classToGetGenerics
     * @param genericPosition
     *
     * @return the generic class of the given param, based on class to get generics and generic position params.
     *
     * @see ObjectUtil#getGenericType
     * @see GenericTypeResolver#resolveTypeArguments
     */
    public static Class<?> getGenericType( Class<?> classInstance, Class<?> classToGetGenerics, int genericPosition ) {
        Class<?>[] typeArguments = getGenericType( classInstance, classToGetGenerics );
        if( typeArguments != null && typeArguments.length >= genericPosition ) {
            return typeArguments[genericPosition];
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Could not determine generic type for interface " + classInstance.getName() );
    }
    
    // ... 
}
```

So we can use like the example below (I created a QueryUtil to handle specifically persistence stuff):

```
@UtilityClass
public class QueryUtil {

    // ...

    /**
     *
     * @param repositoryClass
     *
     * @return the @Entity class of the given repository param.
     *
     * @see ObjectUtil#getGenericType(Class, Class, int)
     * @see ObjectUtil#getGenericType(Class, Class)
     */
    public static Class<?> getRepositoryEntityType( Class<?> repositoryClass ) {
        return ObjectUtil.getGenericType( repositoryClass, Repository.class, 0 );
    }

}
```

---

I hope this is still useful. Here it was used in a customized audit logic, made by aspects, so that the Entity is audited.

Comment: Formatting is a bit off. Otherwise, it's a good answer.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson thanks for advice! How can I improve the formatting? Do you talk about code formatting or textual structure?

Comment: There is text that is block-quoted, and it makes it seem like you are quoting someone else but I suspect it is your own comments.

Comment: Ok! I tried to make a better reading experience now.

Comment: I tend to use ">" as notes in markdown texts... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's [GenericTypeResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html) to get the Entity class from your Repository.

```
Repository<Foo, String> fooRepository = repositories.stream()
    .filter(repository -> GenericTypeResolver
        .resolveTypeArguments(repository.getClass(), Repository.class)[0].equals(Foo.class))
    .findFirst().get();
```