# How to retrieve all Data Repository methods in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reflection, repository

I have a Spring Boot application and I want to list all Data Repositories and also all the methods for each repository. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing so that [leverages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307686/1078565) `spring-data-commons`

```
Repositories repositories = new Repositories(context.getBeanFactory());
Iterator it = repositories.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext()) {
  Class<?> domainClass = (Class<?>) it.next();
  //Get Repositories
  repositories.getRepositoryFor(domainClass);
  //Get Query Methods
  List<QueryMethod> methods = repositories.getQueryMethodsFor(domainClass);
 }
```

**Note**: The above code only fetches the automatically implemented Spring Data Query methods.  If you need all Query methods including those from the provided interfaces (e.g. CrudRepository) as well as custom Query method implementations then use the following:

```
Repositories repositories = new Repositories(context.getBeanFactory());
Iterator it = repositories.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    Class<?> domainClass = (Class<?>) it.next();
    Advised repoProxy = (Advised)repositories.getRepositoryFor(domainClass);
    Class<?>[] interfaces = repoProxy.getProxiedInterfaces();
    List<Method> methods = Arrays.stream(interfaces)
                    .flatMap(c -> Arrays.stream(ReflectionUtils.getAllDeclaredMethods(c)))
                    .collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KyleAnderson that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: getQueryMethodsFor() doesn't return query methods from custom repositories (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) . How could I get this methods?

Comment: @JoseRomero I've added another option to my answer which satisfies your requirement.

Comment: @KyleAnderson I need to have a list of all repositories. How can I make it by using this class? You can find more details about my use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194634/spring-boot-get-a-list-of-repositories-in-non-runner-classes). I have a class that all my repositories extended that. I need something like `List<BaseRepository> repositories` .

Comment: where is the context coming from? is this a variable?