# Get Repository for Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I have Entities like:

```
@Entity
public class Book  extends AbstractPersistable {
 // some fields
}
```

and a Repositories like:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Book> {
    Collection<Book> findByAuthorsContains(Author author);

    Collection<Book> findByShelf(Shelf shelf);

    Optional<Book> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

Now I want to get the repository of one Entity to find the Entity by ID. But I don't know how I can get a instance of the e.g. BookRepository. I created the following Methods:

```
    @Override
public Collection<.datatransfer.graphql.Field> getFieldOfEntity(String entity, Long id) {
    Class<? extends AbstractPersistable> entityClass = getClassesOfTransferDataTypes().stream()
            .filter(aClass -> aClass.getSimpleName().equals(entity))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
    if (entityClass != null) {
        JpaRepository repository = getClassRepositoryOfEntity(entityClass);
        Object one = repository.getOne(id);
        return createFields(one);
    }
    return null;
}

private JpaRepository getClassRepositoryOfEntity(Class<? extends AbstractPersistable> entityClass) {
    Set<datatransfer.graphql.Field> fields = new HashSet<>();
    // TODO get Repository for entityClass
    return null;
}

private Collection<datatransfer.graphql.Field> createFields(Object o) {
    // TODO transform o in a list of Fields
    return null;
}
```

The field is:

```
public class Field {
    public String type;         // String or Integer
    public String fieldName;    // title of field
    public String title;        // annotated Title
    public String value;        // value of entity.field
}
```

Can someone help me to fill the `getClassRepositoryOfEntity`-Method?

Comment: Why not use dependency injection to get that instance e.g.                               @Autowired                                                                                                             
 private BookRepository bookRepository;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: use an entityManager directly. You can find an entity of any class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-

If you are convinced that you need through spring repository,  look at [How to retrieve spring data repository instance for given domain class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266089/how-to-retrieve-spring-data-repository-instance-for-given-domain-class)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The Solution is so easy. Obviously I was a loot of mind fucked :(

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, consider accepting it.